# Unable to enter '/' using send_keys() in Selenium Python in Chrome of RHEL7

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

While sending '0/0/0/6' from selenium webdriver but on UI its displaying without '/', though it works fine with Firefox.

I have tried below options:

1 - `driver.send_keys('0/0/0/6')` , output is '0006'.

2 - `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '0/0/0/6';",element)`, output is NULL.

3 - Also tried through `ActionChains()` but still same output.

Comment: Can you insert the URL so we can see the input in which you want to type the specific string?

Comment: Can you find element, and then send_keys ? instead of `driver.send_keys`

Comment: tried.. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following part of the code and tell me this is working for you?

Because when I am executing it, the result is the proper one.

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys("0/0/0/6")

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: it sends "0/0/0/6".

Comment: haha really? what's the URL of the platform you are testing. I need to see the input. And the problem is in Chrome?

Comment: actually its an internal website and yes issue is in chrome though works fine in FF.

Comment: Then I can't help as I want because I can't see it myself. It's a strange issue and since I can't reproduce it, I can't say what's wrong. Sorry